# Meaning of 'hue" in seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, kaggle, seaborn

[image]

I know what "hue" does a little

I'm studying kaggle and the image is about bike sharing demand analysis

What I want to know is

shouldn't the second images's sum of each point's y axis be the first images's point's y axis??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would expect that to be the case, however, by default `seaborn.pointplot` uses the average estimator to calculate the number for each hour. So the numbers you are seeing on the y-axis is the average number of bikes shared for each hour. Since the number of bikes shared is not equal for category `workingday=0` and `workingday=1` the two averages for those categories do not add up. Using `estimator=sum` for `seaborn.pointplot` does give the expected results.

[image]

Comment: you are right I missed "It is important to keep in mind that a point plot shows only the mean (or other estimator) value" in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html